# ¿Debo pronunciar la 'a' del grupo 'ae' en locuciones latinas?

Tags: pronunciación, locuciones, latinismo

Las siguientes según el DRAE son "locuciones latinas", y me parece que son bastante frecuentes:

- [**curriculum vitae**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Bk6QU1r)
- [**lapsus linguae**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MvluEsL)
- [**ab aeterno**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=00qa1LD)

Mi hábito es pronunciar la [a] de vitae, pero no pronunciar la de linguae, es decir, [bitáe] pero [língwe]. ¿Cuál es la regla al respecto?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Más que una regla precisa, la RAE da un [criterio general](http://www.rae.es/diccionario-panhispanico-de-dudas/que-contiene/tratamiento-de-los-extranjerismos):

1. Se mantiene la pronunciación y grafía original en ***extranjerismos asentados en el uso internacional en su forma original***, como ballet, blues, jazz *o* software.
2. Adaptación o la pronunciación o la grafía. Se hace con el objetivo de *preservar el alto grado de cohesión entre forma gráfica y pronunciación característico* del castellano. Puede tomar distintas formas, como la adaptación de la grafía (ej. *chucrut*) o sólo de la pronunciación.

En el caso de la adaptación de la pronunciación sin la grafía (la RAE propone como ejemplo la pronunciación del anglicismo *airbag* como [airbág] en desmedro de [érbag]), en algunos paises de latinoamérica con mayor influencia británica o estadounidense muchos ejemplos nos suenan mal y preferimos no adaptar nada. Creo que en estos países también hay una componente de *cultismo* (o *esnobismo*, si se la mira negativamente), en preferir la pronunciación original en terreno gris.

El criterio propuesto resulta ambiguo con los **latinismos**. Creo que todos los que citas califican como *asentados en el uso internacional*, pero las reglas de pronunciación dan lugar a un alcance importante.

Respecto a la pronunciación del latín (como idioma, no de los latinismos en particular), desde la Edad Media hasta c. 1900 las reglas de pronunciación del latín eran muy variables según el idioma nativo del que hablaba, y en castellano era universal pronunciar más o menos tal como se lee. Recién en el s. XX se establecieron dos normas de pronunciación *universales* del latín: la ***eclesiástica*** (parecida, pero no igual, a como lo leería un italiano) y la ***reconstruida*** (que intenta deducir como se pronunciaba el latín clásico).

Pronunciar el grupo *ae* en latín como [e] es característico de la pronunciación eclesiástica, y por razones lógicas es lo más común en el mundo de habla hispana (no así en Alemania o los países de habla inglesa).

Como conclusión, y **en respuesta a tu pregunta**, no diría que hay una regla universal, pero sí que es importante ser coherente: o siempre [e], o siempre [ae] (como diptongo para la pronunciación reconstruida), o siempre [a.e] (como hiato, para la pronunciación castellana anterior al s. XX o si quieres adaptarla).

Comment: Y si he de dar mi opinión como latinista aficionado, prefiero siempre [e]

Comment: Solo por expandir un poco más, viendo el post de Rodrigo: el diptongo /ae/, cuando es la desinencia casual (genitivo en *vitae*, por ejemplo), nunca lleva el acento prosódico. Es decir: [ˈbitae], no *[biˈtae].

Aquí explico eso (y más): https://www.delcastellano.com/errores-pronunciacion-latin/

Comment: @Paco Jamás imaginé que fuera esdrújula...

Comment: @Rodrigo ojo que es esdrújulo _per accidens_ y sólo en la pronunciación adaptada: en la eclesiástica se pronuncia ['vi.te] y en la reconstruida el grupo /ae/ es diptongo: ['vi.tae]